# Bootstrap navbar doesnt hide after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

How to change data-offset-top for mobile view? Also, on click  link doesn't hide the menu. I tried some founded code from stackoverflow but no luck. Could someone please help with this link below :

http://smalldesigncompany.com/client/agami/s4/index.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default zero-mar" >
                  <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>



            </div><!--NAVBAR-HEADER-->

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 pull-left">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a class="scroll" href="#top">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="scroll" href="#people">Meet Our People</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a class="scroll" href="#projects">Our Capabilities</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                         <a class="scroll" href="#process">Our Process</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a class="scroll" href="#why">Why Agami</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="projects.html"><span class="right">Projects</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"><span class="right">Contact</span></a></li>

                 </ul>
              </div>
             <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: http://tadhanilalji.blogspot.in/2015/06/bootstrap-navigation-close-in-mobile.html

Comment: you have multiple **IDs** on your `navbar-collapse`!! `pull-left` should be in the `class` attribute of the same `div`

Comment: hi thanks for help but no luck i tried this link http://tadhanilalji.blogspot.in/2015/06/bootstrap-navigation-close-in-mobile.html

Comment: i removed pull left id

Comment: '$('.nav a').click(function(){
    $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
});'   **i added this also but no luck**

Comment: Did you load jQuery.js before Bootstrap.js

Comment: @Tonza yes i loaded jQuery.js before Bootstrap.js

Answer (score 2):

This answer might make think I oversimplify the thing, but often I see jquery/bootstrap scripts loaded twice, and that means two listeners waiting for the button toggle. The first one opens, the second one closes instantly.

Solution: look for scripts loaded twice via browser inspecting (F12) and remove where is convenient.

Comment: Yes, exactly this. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function () {
        $(".navbar-toggle").click() //bootstrap 3.x 
    });
```

Comment: i added but still not achieving [http://smalldesigncompany.com/client/agami/s4/index.html]

Comment: check console getting some error  - ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

> Never use multiple IDs on same div

And for the `navbar-toggle` just use *ID* of your `navbar-collapse` menu in the `data-target` attribute of the `navbar-toggle` as:

```
data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
```

And for hiding the `navbar-collapse` menu again you have to `trigger` the click of your `navbar-toggle` button on the click of `.navbar-nav > li > a` as:

### Code Snippet

```js
$('.navbar-nav > li > a').on('click', function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default zero-mar">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>



    </div>
    <!--NAVBAR-HEADER-->

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#top">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#people">Meet Our People</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#projects">Our Capabilities</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#process">Our Process</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#why">Why Agami</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="projects.html"><span class="right">Projects</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"><span class="right">Contact</span></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: in snippet also not working it should closed na when we click on any link but its not closing

Comment: you haven't added the trigger script from the snippet. remove the script from the header, and add the script of the snippet to your footer or any custom js or something.

Comment: i did what you said what still no luck i am missing something i think  [ http://smalldesigncompany.com/client/agami/s4/index.html ]

Comment: can you also help me in changing the data-offset-top value when in mobile screen

Comment: upvote and accept the answer will be more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.navbar-nav > li > a').on('click', function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default zero-mar">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>



    </div>
    <!--NAVBAR-HEADER-->

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#top">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#people">Meet Our People</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#projects">Our Capabilities</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#process">Our Process</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="scroll" href="#why">Why Agami</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="projects.html"><span class="right">Projects</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"><span class="right">Contact</span></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```